# LaTeX template for the journal "Blood"

Tags: templates, journal

Does anybody know where I can find a LaTeX template for publishing articles in "Blood", the journal of the American society of Hematology?

Comment: Let me Google that for you... http://bloodjournal.hematologylibrary.org/site/authors/authorguide.xhtml#format

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you have time,you can build your own based on the journal requirements using `article` or [scrartcl](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes with tweaking or simply use Word template. Some templates library: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/ https://www.writelatex.com/templates, http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/academic-journals and http://www.howtotex.com/templates/

Comment: Hehe, nice tag `=)`

Comment: @Jake: It's gone now. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: `:'(`