# How can I add chapter support to and find information about the paper class?

Tags: chapters, document-classes

I typed `paper` instead of `report` by accident as the argument of `\documentclass`... and discovered that `paper` is very, very nice. However, it doesn't seems to support chapters.

How can I add chapter support to it or adapt report/books to looks like documents using the `paper` class?

Further, where I can find more information about `paper`? Googling "paper latex" didn't return anything relevant or useful...

Comment: Google “paper.cls” instead.

Comment: It's another class derived from `ar­ti­cle` class from terminal type [`texdoc paper`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/paper/paper.pdf) gives only a german documentation. Have a look at  http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paper

Comment: @texenthusiast Do you know if there is any similar package with documentation available in English? i.e. a generic journal-article class.

Comment: @cfr No idea as such(as some journals might have their own templates/classes), but one may use `article` or more flexible [scrartcl](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) as they are widely popular. `report` for thesis writing

Comment: @texenthusiast Fair enough. I use `article` at the moment but it would be nice to have standard commands for keywords, institution etc. out of the box. (I know I can create these. I already have for some other things.) For my thesis, I used a variant of `amsbook` which is slightly bizarre but worked. (Only bizarre because my thesis contained essentially no mathematics whatsoever.) Journals I submit to rarely provide classes/templates. Usually, they insist on Word for final submission but will take PDF initially. Hence a generic option would be ideal.

Comment: @cfr  Yes journals are like that I understand, we have to live with that :). If I were you I would have used scrartcl or [some template links](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153389/latex-template-for-the-journal-blood#comment350360_153389) Even [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) is nice alternative. anyway Good luck :)

Comment: Could you say what it is you like about the `paper` class? That might help people suggest things you could use to adapt another class. Classes which support layouts for books which involve chapters, front matter, back matter and so on tend to involve quite a lot absent from classes designed for articles. So while you could easily add a `\chapter` command, for instance, this might not give you the sorts of results you are hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

As  texenthusiast said, `texdoc` is your friend, but the little documentation is in german only (although with a english abstract). Nonetheless, the functions of the few new commands that you will see as `\smalltableofcontents`  are rather obvious, but in any case you can just ignore these commands  and use only the standard `article` commands.  May be is helping also the examples that you can see just [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121705/11604).

About the book type alternatives, probably the most similar european look without any tuning is obtained with the `scrbook` class. Moreover is highly customizable.  In this case  with `texdoc scrbook`you will obtain a well documented english manual ... of 421 pages!